# Mongoose Updating an array in multiple documents by passing an array of filters to update query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have multiple documents(3 documents in this example) in one collection that looks like this:

```
{
   _id:123,
   bizs:[{_id:'',name:'a'},{_id:'',name:'b'}]
},

{
  _id:456,
  bizs:[{_id:'',name:'e'},{_id:'',name:'f'}]
}

{
  _id:789,
  bizs:[{_id:'',name:'x'},{_id:'',name:'y'}]
}
```

Now, I want to update the bizs subdocument by matching with my array of ids.
 That is to say, my array filter for update query is [123,789], which will match against the _id fields of each document.
I have tried using **findByIdAndUpdate()** but that doesn't allow an array for the update query

How can I update the 2 matching documents (like my example above) without having to put findByIdAndUpdate inside a forloop to match the array element with the _id?

Comment: Do you've the same value to be updated for those two docs or each doc has a different value to be updated ?

Comment: @srinivasy 

It is the same values to be updated for those two docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use [findByIdAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) when updating multiple documents,  `findByIdAndUpdate` is from mongoose which is a wrapper to native MongoDB's [findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/index.html). When you pass a single string as a filter to `findByIdAndUpdate` like : `Collection.findByIdAndUpdate({'5e179dac627ef7823643cd97'}, {})` - then mongoose will internally convert `string` to `ObjectId()` & form it as a filter like :`_id : ObjectId('5e179dac627ef7823643cd97')` to execute `findOneAndUpdate`. So it means you can only update one document at a time, So if you've multiple documents to be updated use [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/index.html) with option `{multi : true}` or [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html).

Assume if you wanted to push a new object to `bizs`, this is how query looks like :

```
collection.updateMany({ _id: { $in: [123, 456] } }, {
    $push: {
        bizs: {
            "_id": "",
            "name": "new"
        }
    }
})
```

**Note :** Update operations doesn't return the documents in response rather they will return **write result** which has information about n docs matched & n docs modified.